# Finished with my scene but when I go to render it, it shows up blank

Tags: rendering

I have a google drive file to help anyone figure out if im doing something wrong. Thanks!

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1FmNSs4zZOaYIwcsez0Hfdv8IF5ksiM3R/view

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Some things to consider first- Is there a camera in your scene? If so, is it pointed the right way? If so, is the end-clip distance of your camera sufficient encompass your scene? If so, is there a hidden object in your viewport that is blocking the camera (hidden objects are still visible in renders)? If not, is there enough lighting in your scene? - These are all common starting points.

Comment: It is nothing from @ChristopherBennett suggestions ... since it works for me quite fine, isn't it just you didn't wait until Render bar (at bottom row) finish the job?

Comment: Weird thing was for me it rendered like with 1 sample even there is set 4096 (even with low Noise Threshold) ... when whole Collection appended into a new file it was fine. So not only long time to load scene to render (btw it can be speed it up with Performance > Final Render > Persistent Data for the next time), but some another issue in properties setup that I cant see.

Comment: BTW if you experience some differences between Viewport /Render - instead of sharing huge file, try to delete all objects that doesn't participate on issue. Like that you can discover issue by your self or you end up with a lite blend file to share.

Answer (score 0):

I downloaded your file and figured it out I think. *Show Overlays* is turned off in the right window so when you try to do a viewport render it just looks grey. However, if you turn overlays back on, you can see that it is stuck on: `loading render Kernels (this may take a few minutes the first time)`.

I googled this message and it seems to be related to using [OptiX denoiser](https://developer.nvidia.com/optix-denoiser). Maybe if you wait a long time it will load but I just turn the denoiser setting to this:

[image]

and it rendered almost instantly for me. Let me know if that works.